# Axios returning a promise object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm trying to make an API call with async/await using Axios. The API code is working however I'm getting a promise object instead of the data array I would expect.

Console Log:

```
{<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: Array(10)0:
```

Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const apiTest = async (props) => {
  try {
    const payload = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      responseType: "json"
    });

    return payload.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`error found of type ${err}`);
  }
};

export default apiTest;
```

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen - async functions **always** return promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions do not return values like non-async functions.

They actually return promises that either:

1. Resolve with the returned values.
2. Reject with the thrown errors.

so you can use your data like this:

```
apiTest().then(data=> ...
```

Comment: I see where I was confused.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Call your function like this

```
apiTest().then(response=>{
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the async/await just add await before calling `apiTest` function.
And because you cannot tag `async` the useEffect callback you might add the `apiTest` function inside your component, and instead of returning `payload.data` you will have to set your state with `payload.data`